# NFS Server granting/removing share permissions to a host error

Tags: windows, permissions, vmware, windows-server-2012-r2, nfs

While trying to add a host to NFS share permissions I'm receiving a very generic error with not much to go on.

```
Cannot set NFS permissions Failed to perform the requested operation.
```

The NFS server is a Windows 2012 R2 core server. I've tried doing this both via the UI (Server Manager tool) and directly from the box with powershell.

[image: Windows share permissions UI screen]

```
[server-name]: PS F:\Shares> Grant-NfsSharePermission -Name "<share-name>" -ClientName "<client-name>" -ClientType "host" -Permission "readwrite" -AllowRootAccess:$true
Grant-NfsSharePermission : Failed to perform the requested operation.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NfsServerTasks:root/Microsoft/..._NfsServerTasks) [Grant-NfsShareP
   ermission], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070490,Grant-NfsSharePermission
```

I've redacted the server/client names as I don't think that's really relevant. I'm getting the same error when trying to remove any of the existing hosts as well. The server itself hosts a number of shares and it's only this one that throws this issue. i.e I can add, remove or edit permissions on any other share on the server bar this one. If it's relevant the server is virtual(VmWare) and the Volumes for the shares are virtual disks.

I've found a very similar issue on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681658/revoke-nfssharepermission-on-windows2012-results-in-an-error) with no answers but a comment from the poster himself saying he bypassed the issue by using the "FailOverClusterManager menu". In my case the shares are not clustered nor am I aware of any way to grant permissions from the cluster manager. Nothing related to this issue is coming up in the Event Viewer and a full server reboot didn't help.

I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days with this problem so any insights/pointers would be really appreciated.

Edit - adding the output of `Get-NfsSharePermission` and `Revoke-NfsSharePermission` commands as suggested in the comments.

```
[server-name]: PS F:\Shares> Get-NfsSharePermission <share-name> 

Name                          ClientName                    Permission                    AllowRootAccess
----                          ----------                    ----------                    ---------------
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      <client-name>                 READ, WRITE                   True
<share-name>                      All Machines                  DENY ACCESS                   False
```

```
[server-name]: PS F:\Shares> Revoke-NfsSharePermission -ClientName "client-name" -ClientType host -Name "<share-name>"
Revoke-NfsSharePermission : Failed to perform the requested operation.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NfsServerTasks:root/Microsoft/..._NfsServerTasks) [Revoke-NfsShare
   Permission], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070490,Revoke-NfsSharePermission
```

Comment: Another Toughy Issue. The Debugging Processes are generally difficult. Debugging Network Administrative Issues is even more difficult. We would cling onto your comment: "_it's only this one that throws this issue_" and to the `CategoryInfo` Attribute of the _PowerShell_ `CimException`: `ObjectNotFound`. Something is definitely wrong with that share.

Comment: We would attempt to approach it the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ way: if it is possible, remove that share. Create it again. Attempt to set its permissions again. If it is still not working, then try to understand _how_ it is in any way different than the other shares. What makes it special. Even in the terms of the users that it is addressing.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Thanks for the response. The thing that makes it difficult to troubleshoot is that this share is actively used by a number of hosts so I can't really offline it at will. `ObjectNotFound` bit is strange to me as `Get-NfsSharePermission` command works fine so the "object" mustn't be refferring to the share itself.  I've tried comparing the permissions and setup with working shares across a few servers but can't see anything that stands out. Was hoping someone was in a similar situation who could advise so I could avoid having to recreate it.

Comment: So the `Get` is working, but the `Grant` is not working. The `ObjectNotFound` `CimException` appears to be referring to the `NfsServerTasks` Object. Maybe you could insert both your `Get` and your `Grant` in the body of your question so that other Network Administrators might see what you have done so far and further help you.

Comment: I've added the output of `Get` and `Revoke` (since I had the output of `Get` in there before)

Comment: Yes, the `Get` was there already, but nicely framed in a photo frame. As suggested to us once by @Kamil Maciorowski on this Web-Site, if you want other people to find issues that are similar to yours, it would be better if you converted it to plain text. Your issue is quite exotic and does not seem to have much similarities out there, on the Internet.

Comment: Only meant that the `Revoke` gives the same error as `Grant` so wanted to avoid duplication in terms of information but I take your point and have replaced the image with a text block.

Comment: From our own experience, we already know how difficult the System, Network and DataBase Administrative work is. We wish you best of luck in your quest and hope that maybe some other Network Administrators will come and take a look at your Issue. Sadly, we cannot help you any further with it.

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason, Windows NFS updates the entire list of NFS clients whenever you add or remove a client. Granting permissions for a new client will fail if there is one or more, of the existing clients, that are not up and running.
As a workaround, Check the list of existing clients, remove those that are not reachable and add your new NFS client. (unfortunately DR clients that are not running must be removed also)
Note: Click apply only after removing all unreachable hosts

```
 $ShareName="NFS_ShareName"
    $nfsClients= Get-NfsSharePermission  $ShareName
    foreach( $client in $nfsClients.ClientName){
     if (!(Test-Connection -Computername $client -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -Quiet)){ 
        write $client
     }
   }
```

Comment: It worked for me , thank you!